# End Script when "User is already a member of group"

Tags: powershell

I have a script I'm using to auto add domain users into a specific group. It also incorporates a stop/restart of a 3rd party service that adds them into a secure user file. I'd like for this script to end the moment it finds that the user is already a part of the group, and NOT stop/start the service. This is what I have so far:

> ```
> Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerNameHere -ScriptBlock {add-LocalGroupMember -Group "GroupNameHere" -Member $env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME }
> *--Add in line here that terminates the script once user is found to already be a member and not restart the service below*
> Stop-Service -Name "ServiceNameHere"
> timeout /t 5 /nobreak
> Start-Service -Name "ServiceNameHere"
> ```

When I run the script, I get the below message, which is normal, and then the script continues to run, thus restarting the service anyway.

```
Domain\User is already a member of group GroupName
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceExists: (GroupName:String) [Add-LocalGroupMember], MemberExistsException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MemberExists,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddLocalGroupMemberCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ServerName
```

Comment: You forgot to put in your “add in line” where you attempt to check if the user is in the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Cpt.Whale for helping me on this.

I was running into the PowerShell "Get-LocalGroupMember - Failed to compare two elements in the array." bug as described [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2996) when you have orphaned SIDs. I came across this post [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/dohgip/removing_sid_from_local_admins/) that helped me figure out how to remove the orphaned SIDs. Below is the new fully working script.

Important Note: You need PowerShell V5.1 for this. Also, you have to enable remote signing. From Powershell check first with a simple "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" (may as well run "winrm quickconfig", as well).

Working Script:

```
$strComputer = 'ServerNameHere'
$serviceName = 'ServiceNameHere'

#Remove orphaned SIDs from Windows Local Groups
$computer = [ADSI]("WinNT://" + $strComputer + ",computer")
$group = $computer.psbase.children.find("LocalGroupNameHere")
$group.Name
$Userlist = ([ADSI]"WinNT://$strComputer/LocalGroupNameHere").psbase.Invoke('Members') | % { ([ADSI]$_).InvokeGet('AdsPath') }
#For each user in that list, if the name is a SID, Remove the specific SID from the group. 
foreach ($user in $Userlist) {
if ($user -like "WinNT://S-1-5-*") {
#Remove the specific SID from the group, as passed as a string (not an object).
$group.remove($user)}
}

$Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $strComputer -ScriptBlock {
  # Check whether user is already a member of group
  If ((Get-LocalGroupMember 'LocalGroupNameHere').Name -notcontains "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME") {
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'LocalGroupNameHere' -Member "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" 
    Write-Output $True
  }
  Else { Write-Output $False }
}

# If group membership changed, restart service:
If ($Result) {
  (get-service -ComputerName $strComputer -Name $serviceName).Stop()
  timeout /t 5 /nobreak
  (get-service -ComputerName $strComputer -Name $serviceName).Start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check the output of `Invoke-Command` before restarting the service:

```
$Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName ServerNameHere -ScriptBlock {
  # Check whether user is already a member of group
  If ((Get-LocalGroupMember 'GroupNameHere').Name -notcontains "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME") {
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group 'GroupNameHere' -Member "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME" 
    Write-Output $True
  }
  Else { Write-Output $False }
}

# If group membership changed, restart service:
If ($Result) {
  Stop-Service -Name "ServiceNameHere"
  timeout /t 5 /nobreak
  Start-Service -Name "ServiceNameHere"
}
```

Comment: Yes! It worked brilliantly! I know this sort of stuff probably seems easy for you (and many others), but this just made my afternoon. Thanks for the quick help - truly appreciated!

Comment: Cpt.Whale, this script has been running great. Unfortunately, if there is an unresolved SID (e.g. an employee leaves the company) in the Windows group, the script errors and reboots the service anyway.

    FullyQualifiedErrorId : An unspecified error occurred.,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetLocalGroupMemberCommand

I’ve read here that this is a known bug in PowerShell 5.1 and higher:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2996

Might you have any ideas for a workaround?